# ManagedServiceFactory using Blueprint

Tags: osgi, blueprint-osgi

The registration of a ManagedServiceFactory follows can be done as :-

```
private ServiceRegistration factoryService;
public void start(BundleContext context) {
    Dictionary props = new Hashtable();
    props.put("service.pid", "test.smssenderfactory");
    factoryService = context.registerService(ManagedServiceFactory.class.getName(),
        new SmsSenderFactory(), props);
}
```

How can one do this in a blueprint(Sample example would be highly useful) ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache aries has support for Managed services. You can find examples in the integration tests of Apache Aries blueprint at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/aries/trunk/blueprint/blueprint-itests/src/test/resources/ManagedServiceFactoryTest.xml. In this case can change the code of your SMSSenderFactory not to implement ManagedServiceFactory directly as blueprint does it for you.

You can also embed your code (that you gave as a sample in your question) into the init-method of your bean if that was your question. In that case the ManagedServiceFactory should be unregistered in the destroy method of the bean.

Third option is to leave blueprint out of the game. You already have a ManagedServiceFactory implementation, why don't you simply register it in the Activator of the Bundle?

Fourth option is to use [Declarative Services](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-service-component-runtime.html) with one of the annotation set. In that case Metatype information will be also generated and you can configure your SMSSender via the webconsole.

I suggest you to use the last option.